# Migrate only customer and sales orders tables from Magento 2.1 to 2.4.1

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, magento2.4.1

I need to migrate customer and sales tables from Magento 2.1 to 2.4.1. What would be the best way to do it ? As i know, magento provides migration tool. From the manuel, i see this tool is used for migration from magento 1 to magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

Yuksel

You can use Magento default data-migration-tool to do it. But from my experience, the configuration is pretty complicated and many errors can happen! I would suggest you hire a highly-professional third-party to avoid all the hassles.